# Python to Ruby Conversion, stuck on the equivalent

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have this string that hashes the password to connect to the server properly. It works fine for the hashing in python

```
import hmac
"password": hmac.new(user_pasw.encode(), (user_name + resp["challenge"]).encode(), "md5").hexdigest().upper()
```

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find the equivalent of to do the tuple without other gems being installed. Thus, im stuck. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be absolute ruby equivalent of provided python code

```
require 'openssl'
password = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(
  user_passw.force_encoding("UTF-8"),
  (user_name + resp["challenge"]).force_encoding("UTF-8"),
  'md5'
).upcase

{ password: password }
```

I'm pretty sure you can omit `force_encoding`, though. It should work anyway

Comment: Almost, getting this error.... RuntimeError Unsupported digest algorithm (cleuber).: first num too large I think by looking at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html ill have to do another variable...

Comment: Yeah my attempt failed :/

Comment: @walkamile could you, please, provide user_passw, user_name and challenge, so i could replicate the error?

Comment: Never mind you were 95% right :D. Idiotcally changed a variable in my test, and then adjusted yours a bit and worked swell! THANK YOU. In the end this is what works. Yours was PERFECT just had to change some stuff to get it work :D hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('md5'), password.to_s, (username.to_s + challenge.to_s)).upcase